# What classifies data as JSONP and how can I get it with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, same-origin-policy

So I've recently learned how to do an AJAX call and know that I need to use JSONP when working with APIs from outside servers. As I learned from sitepoint, it was pointed out that the difference of JSONP is that it is wrapped in a function making it accessible through a script tag.

SitePoint Link: https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/
E.g http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/v8xyYN64V4nqCshgjKms/data-2.json

Although what I don't understand is the Flickr API for JSONP.

**Flickr API Link JSONP:**
https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?
**Flickr API Link XML:** 
https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?

It seems to return XML data instead. What confuses me even more is that this type of xml is accepted by jQuery's $.getJSON() while it's original api also in xml causes the same origin policy error. The main difference I could find between them are a few href changes.

So what makes the XML of flickr JSONP and how can I make an ajax call with it in plain javascript?

Any feedback on this will be greatly appreciated : )

**Update for clarity:**

```
Here I have working code using the flickr XML that does an ajax call with jQuery.
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan002/05ao4d87/

I was taught that this is only made possible by JSONP in treehouse. https://teamtreehouse.com/library/ajax-basics/ajax-and-apis/displaying-the-photos. If I am not using JSONP to accomplish this task, what is allowing me to circumvent the same origin policy?

Comment: *"So what makes the XML of flickr JSONP..."* Nothing, the response from the link you've said returns JSONP doesn't. It returns XML. I suggest doing a bit more research, for instance, [reading the JSONP Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you've said returns JSONP doesn't, it returns XML. The [flickr documentation](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html) tells us you need `format=json` in the URL; you also want to fill in something where the `?` is so you name the callback function (although if you use jQuery, it will do that for you). For instance: https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=callbackName

Note: They call it JSON, but it isn't. It's JSONP. [JSON](http://json.org) and [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) are different things. The bit inside the call to the callback is valid JSON, though (not all JSONP responses are).

Here's an example of JSON:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

Here's an example of JSONP using valid JSON within the callback:

```
callbackName({"foo": "bar"})
```

Here's an example of JSONP using invalid JSON within the callback (but it works, because JSONP and JSON are different things):

```
callbackName({foo: "bar"})
```

> how can I get it with plain javascript?

The [jQuery documentation for `$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) describes how to do JSON calls with jQuery. In this case:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
    success: function(data) {
        // Use the data here
        console.log("The title is: " + data.title);
    },
    error: function() {
        // Handle error here
        console.log("Error loading the data");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that since flickr are using a non-standard name for the parameter that controls the name of the callback, you need the `jsonp` option telling jQuery what parameter name to use.

Comment: Here I have working code using the flickr XML that does an ajax call with jQuery. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan002/05ao4d87/

I was taught that this is only made possible by JSONP in treehouse. https://teamtreehouse.com/library/ajax-basics/ajax-and-apis/displaying-the-photos. If I am not using JSONP to accomplish this task, what is allowing me to circumvent the same origin policy?

Comment: Sorry it entered the text when I was trying to do alt enter and posted it prematurely. I updated the answer just now.

Comment: @Jonathan002: You are using JSONP, because you've used `format: "json"` in your `flickrOptions`, which get appended to the URL. (You can see this in the Network tab of your browser; the actual URL requested by `$.getJSON`, because of those options, is `https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=jQueryblahblahblah&tags=Dog&format=json&_=1486914520263` (the values of `jsoncallback` and `_` vary). I'm a bit surprised that's working without the `jsonp` option, but I guess jQuery just looks for `callback=?` without worrying about whether it's a partial match.